# Exporting chart.js charts to svg using canvas2svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, chart.js

I am trying to export [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) chart to svg using [canvas2svg.js](https://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/).

It does not seems to be working, since chart.js refuses to use 'fake' canvas created by canvas2svg.js

**My HTML code:**

```
<div style="position: relative; height:20vh; width:100vh">
<canvas id="radarCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>
```

**My script:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("radarCanvas").getContext("2d");

var radarChart = new Chart(ctx, graphData);  // Works fine


// Create canvas2svg 'fake' context
var c2s = C2S(500,500);

// new chart on 'fake' context fails:
var mySvg = new Chart(c2s, graphData);
// Result (console):
// "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item"
```

I've posted full example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bocko/pen/XaMJzw?editors=1011) (Sorry for long js there, I could not find a link from which to import canvas2svg so I pasted it at the beginnning of the script.)

Comment: Also, I don't insist on nither of two libraries mentioned. I just need nice (preferably animated) radar/polar charts which I can export to SVG. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a recent Chart.JS version (2.7.1 at time of writing) you can get this running by tweaking canvas2svg a bit. 
I added the following code to canvas2svg: Have a look at the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eydPEy?editors=1011)

```
ctx.prototype.getContext = function (contextId) {
    if (contextId=="2d" || contextId=="2D") {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}

ctx.prototype.style = function () {
    return this.__canvas.style
}

ctx.prototype.getAttribute = function (name) {
    return this[name];
}

ctx.prototype.addEventListener =  function(type, listener, eventListenerOptions) {
    console.log("canvas2svg.addEventListener() not implemented.")
}
```

**BUT:** It only works if you disable animation and responsiveness of the chart (set to false).

Comment: Hey, this works great! Thank you. And since I only need svg for exporting, I can use normal settings for chart (animation, responsiveness) until I want to export it, and only then set those to false.

Comment: Another library that may be worth checking out: http://ej2.syncfusion.com/home/ (they have a community license available for devs and companies making less than  $1M/yr). Their charts use svg so exporting comes naturally.

Comment: this worked for me for the given example in codepen however not working with my own graph config. Shows error `TypeError: t.classList is undefined` in mozilla and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` in chrome.

Comment: @rumman0786, I am seeing exaclty the same classList error, did you solve that in the meantime?

Comment: To fix the classList error add this to tweaks : ```ctx.prototype.classList = {
  add: () => {},
}```

Answer (score 7):

In case somebody stumbles across this question, replacing the ctx in sspechts answer to C2S and disabling animation and responsiveness of the graphdata one can get the svg from the canvas.
I forked the codepen project and added one function which tweaks the library with the codesnippets from sspecht and the two flags:

```
// deactivate responsiveness and animation
graphData.options.responsive = false;
graphData.options.animation = false;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYVVPY

Comment: Your codepen example does not work already.

Answer (score 2):

For devices that have a devicePixelRatio different than 1 or are zoomed in/out I did:

```
const getDevicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio
window.devicePixelRatio = 1;
// C2S Code
window.devicePixelRatio = getDevicePixelRatio
```

Otherwise the svg may get cropped.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of Chart.js (3.9.1) seems to use setTransform() and resetTransform() methods which are not implemented by Canvas2SVG ( no updates on github for ~5 years ).

This maintained version does implement theses methods : https://github.com/zenozeng/svgcanvas/  ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgcanvas ).

However, it seems to have issues for drawing line. I wrote a little workaround for that ( see https://github.com/zenozeng/svgcanvas/issues/25 ).

I hope it'll help.