# Draw chart.js as svg

Tags: svg, chart.js

Does anyone know how to edit this solution: 
[Exporting chart.js charts to svg using canvas2svg.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151467/7047342)

so the SVG will be drawn inline the HTML-document and not just as a console.log?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this line so it worked:

```
document.getElementById("SVG-container-name").innerHTML = svgContext.getSerializedSvg(true);
```